# Any Glide is a product of a Half turn and a Reflection. I have a solution, but I can't understand it.

Tags: linear-algebra, euclidean-geometry, function-and-relation-composition, isometry

The plane we are dealing with is $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Notations:

- $H_a = R(a,\pi)$ which means a rotation about the point $a$ for $\pi$.
- $G(l,a)=R_lT_a$ which means a glide that is a composition of a reflection about the line $l$ and a translation with a vector $a$.

I would share a solution for this problem which I'm having trouble understanding.

> Given a line $l$ and $a$ (the solution didn't specify what is $a$, but this should be a vector), choose a point $b$ on $l$.
>
> Then, we can check that $H_bG(l,a)=R_{l'}$, where $l'$ is a perpendicular line to $l$ and $l\cap l'$ is given by $b-\frac{a}{2}$.
>
> Then, $G(l,a)=H_bR_{l'}$.

I'm not really sure how the $l'$ is defined here.

I was assuming that $b-\frac{a}{2}$ gives some point, then we draw a line $l'$ from this point perpendicularly to $l$. However, this didn't really work.

Comment: Given a line and a point in the plane, there is exactly one line that is perpendicular to the given line and passes through the given point. $\ell'$ is the unique line perpendicular to $\ell$ and passing through the point $b - \frac 12a$.

Comment: I think your problem is that you are missing one piece of the definition of a "glide reflection". $a$ is not any vector, but is a vector *pointing along $\ell$*. Since $b$ is on $\ell$, if $a$ does not point along $\ell$, then neither does $\frac 12 a$, and so the translation of $b$ by $-\frac 12 a$ will move off of $\ell$, contrary to the claim that it would be $\ell \cap \ell'$.

Comment: A translation through an amount $a$ followed by a reflection in a line $\ell$ is equal to a half  turn about some point $p$ followed by a reflection in some line $\ell^*$. Choose a co-ordinate system where $p=(0,0)$ and $\ell$ is parallel to the $y$-axis. I think $\ell^*$ is parallel to the $x$-axis.